# Paste event is not getting triggered via paste-execCommand

Tags: javascript, html, copy-paste

**Requirement:**
I do want to extract plain text content (with space/new-line formatting) from Rich Text (DOM).

**Solution I tried:**
Simulated copy event to get the text & html in to clipboardData. So that i can simply take the plain text from clipboardData instead of processing html on my own.

**Problem I am facing:**
I able to get the plain-text data in to clipboardData via copy event, but not able to extract since, paste event handler is not getting invoked

```js
doCopy.addEventListener('click', function() {
  copy('demo');
});

function copy(element_id) {
  var aux = document.createElement("div");
  aux.setAttribute("contentEditable", true);
  aux.innerHTML = document.getElementById(element_id).innerHTML;
  aux.oncopy = function() {
    debugger;
  }
  aux.setAttribute("onfocus", "document.execCommand('selectAll',false,null)");
  document.body.appendChild(aux);
  aux.focus();
  document.execCommand("copy");
  extractPlainText();
  document.body.removeChild(aux);
}

function extractPlainText() {
  var aux = document.createElement("div");
  aux.setAttribute("contentEditable", true);
  aux.setAttribute("onfocus", "document.execCommand('selectAll',false,null)");
  document.body.appendChild(aux);
  aux.onpaste = function() { //Want plain text from DOM+
    debugger;
    var dataTransfer = event.clipboardData,
      data = {};
    for (var i = 0; i < dataTransfer.types.length; i++) {
      var contentType = dataTransfer.types[i];
      data[contentType] = dataTransfer.getData(contentType);
    }
  };
  aux.focus();
  document.execCommand("paste");
  document.body.removeChild(aux);
}
```

```css
#target {
  width: 400px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  overflow: auto;
}

#demo {
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  overflow: auto;
  border: 1px solid green;
}
```

```html
<p id="demo" contentEditable="true"><b>Bold text</b> and <u>underlined text</u>.</p>
<button id="doCopy">Copy Keeping Format</button>

<div id="target" contentEditable="true"></div>
```

JSFiddle link: https://jsfiddle.net/kommugopi/xjcadvyp/8/

Comment: link is not working

Comment: everything explained here: http://w3c.github.io/editing/execCommand.html

Comment: @vv01f I came across *We don't fire events for copy/cut/paste/undo/redo/selectAll because they should all have their own events.* this statement. But, copy event is getting fired though !!

Comment: well, it's a draft: "We fire events as requested in bug 13118. This is a new feature does not currently match any browser. If you are implementing this, please make sure to file any feedback as bugs. The spec is not finalized yet and can still be easily changed." – so expect some quirks

Comment: Seems to be I found the rot cause.. document.execCommand("paste"); statement returning *false*... and then i checked document.queryCommandEnabled('paste').. it returns false.. For more info: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/queryCommandEnabled..

I need to investigate more on this..

Comment: @vv01f Do you know a way to get "text/plain" from "text/html".. as perfect as data in clipBoardData ?

Comment: other question: do you really need the clipboard content for your task or did you just go that way?

Comment: As I said my requirement is to get the plainText form RT.. I believe clipboard plainText content will be accurate when compared with others (content via regular expressions / textContent)